# Unable to get CDI and JAX-RS to work together in Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, jax-rs, cdi, java-ee-7

I have to deploy a project that was working successfully in Wildfly to Glassfish. Everything worked fine except for dependency injection of an object in ResponseFilter. The object is Produced in the REST resource handler. I have created a simple project to demonstrate the issue. I have gone through several answers on Stackoverflow. Tried everything and none seem to work.

bean.xml

```
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```

App.java

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class App extends Application {
}
```

DemoResource.java

```
@Path("/demo")
public class DemoResource {

    @Produces
    private Pojo pojo;

    @GET
    public void demo() {
        pojo = new Pojo();
    }
}
```

Pojo.java

```
@Alternative
public class Pojo {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;
}
```

ResponseFilter.java

```
@Provider
public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    private Pojo injectedPojo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
        throws IOException {

        Instance<Pojo> instance = CDI.current().select(Pojo.class);
        Pojo uninjectedPojo = null;
        if (!instance.isUnsatisfied() && instance.get() != null)
            uninjectedPojo = instance.get();
        System.out.println("Injected POJO: " + injectedPojo);
        System.out.println("Uninjected POJO: " + uninjectedPojo);
    }
}
```

The output in Wildfly log file is:

```
16:33:58,765 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Injected POJO: com.example.demo.Pojo@2092c78b
16:33:58,765 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Uninjected POJO: com.example.demo.Pojo@2092c78b
```

The output in Glassfish log is:

```
[2018-02-14T16:36:37.730+0545] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1518605497730] [levelValue: 800] [[Injected POJO: null]]
[2018-02-14T16:36:37.730+0545] [Payara 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=27 _ThreadName=http-thread-pool::http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1518605497730] [levelValue: 800] [[Uninjected POJO: null]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<alternatives>` declaration to the **beans.xml**

```
<beans ... >
    <alternatives>
        <class>[package name].Pojo</class>
    </alternatives>
</beans>
```

Or add

```
@Priority(Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION+100)
```

anotion to `Pojo` class